# How to write Functor instance of Continuation Monad?

Tags: haskell, continuations, quickcheck, continuation-passing

```
newtype Cont k a = Cont { runCont :: (a -> k) -> k }

instance Functor (Cont k) where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Cont k a) -> (Cont k b)
  fmap f (Cont akTok) = Cont $ ???
```

My doubts:

1. We can only write Functor instance to any data type that can produce a type out (ex: [a], Maybe a, (y -> a)), but not for the data types that consumes a type. Now in the above data type it consumes a function that consumes **a** then how does this indirect consumption's can be considered as producing a type **a**. That means we cannot write Functor instance for **(k -> a) -> k**?
2. How can I read the **Cont** data type. **Cont** produces **k** when it have **a**? (Just like Javascript XHR callback produces JSON when it have response from fetching data from server?)
3. How to write QuickCheck test cases for **Cont** data type

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Checkers
import Test.QuickCheck.Classes

newtype Cont k a = Cont { runCont :: (a -> k) -> k }

instance Functor (Cont k) where
   ...

instance Applicative (Cont k) where
   ...

instance Monad (Cont k) where
   ...

instance (Arbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary (Cont k a) where
    arbitrary = do
        -- akTok <- arbitrary -- How to generate Arbitrary functions like this
        return $ Cont akTok

instance (Eq k, Eq a) => EqProp (Cont k a) where
    (=-=) = eq -- How can I test this equality

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let trigger :: Cont ???
        trigger = undefined
    quickBatch $ functor trigger
    quickBatch $ applicative trigger
    quickBatch $ monad trigger
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Haskell Wikibook chapter on continuations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style) — it’s a great introduction to this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there's at most one valid `Functor` for any type, it's easy to mechanically solve for it. In fact, we can make the compiler do the hard work for us:

```
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set -ddump-deriv -XDeriveFunctor
Prelude> newtype Cont k a = Cont { runCont :: (a -> k) -> k } deriving(Functor)

==================== Derived instances ====================
Derived class instances:
  instance GHC.Base.Functor (Ghci1.Cont k) where
    GHC.Base.fmap f_a1xR (Ghci1.Cont a1_a1xS)
      = Ghci1.Cont
          ((\ b5_a1xT b6_a1xU
              -> (\ b4_a1xV -> b4_a1xV)
                   (b5_a1xT
                      ((\ b2_a1xW b3_a1xX
                          -> (\ b1_a1xY -> b1_a1xY) (b2_a1xW (f_a1xR b3_a1xX)))
                         b6_a1xU)))
             a1_a1xS)
    (GHC.Base.<$) z_a1xZ (Ghci1.Cont a1_a1y0)
      = Ghci1.Cont
          ((\ b6_a1y1 b7_a1y2
              -> (\ b5_a1y3 -> b5_a1y3)
                   (b6_a1y1
                      ((\ b3_a1y4 b4_a1y5
                          -> (\ b2_a1y6 -> b2_a1y6)
                               (b3_a1y4 ((\ b1_a1y7 -> z_a1xZ) b4_a1y5)))
                         b7_a1y2)))
             a1_a1y0)


Derived type family instances:


Prelude>
```

That's a big mess, but it's easy to simplify (just rename some variables, remove functions that are basically `id`, and use `.` instead of writing it out by hand):

```
instance Functor (Cont k) where
  fmap f (Cont k2) = Cont (\k1 -> k2 (k1 . f))
```

It may also be enlightening to consider [`Op`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#t:Op), and defining your `Functor` in terms of its `Contravariant` instance:

```
import Data.Functor.Contravariant

instance Functor (Cont k) where
  fmap f = Cont . getOp . contramap (getOp . contramap f . Op) . Op . runCont
```

Or possibly more easily understandable, with some extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Coerce
import Data.Functor.Contravariant

instance Functor (Cont k) where
  fmap f = coerce (contramap @(Op k) (contramap @(Op k) f))
```

Or foregoing that typeclass entirely, and just noting that its `contramap = flip (.)`:

```
instance Functor (Cont k) where
  fmap f = Cont . contramapFunc (contramapFunc f) . runCont
    where contramapFunc = flip (.)
```

This works since doubled contravariant functors yield a covariant functor.

Yet another option is to remove the newtype wrapper and then just play type Tetris:

```
instance Functor (Cont k) where
  fmap f = Cont . fmapRaw f . runCont
    where
      fmapRaw :: (a -> b) -> ((a -> k) -> k) -> (b -> k) -> k
      fmapRaw f k2 k1 = k2 (k1 . f)
```

Here, we have an `a -> b`, an `(a -> k) -> k`, and a `b -> k`, and we need to combine them to get a `k`. If we compose the `b -> k` with the `a -> b`, we get an `a -> k`, and we can then give that to the `(a -> k) -> k` to get a `k`.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me out. Can you also please help me how to generate arbitrary functions in QuickCheck.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: personally I'm lost in all the differently typed `k1`s and `k2`s,  but `fmap ab (Cont akk) = Cont (\bk -> akk (bk . ab))` or `fmapRaw ab akk bk = akk (bk . ab)` I *can* follow. :) also, you might need `InstanceSigs` for the last one.